# Weird Hibernate issue saveOrupdate or merge (both not working)

Tags: hibernate, merge

We have an Email object.

The email.hbm has

```
<bag name="emailRecipients" lazy="false" inverse="false"
             cascade="save-update" fetch="select">
            <key column="EMAIL_ID" />           
            <one-to-many class="EmailRecipient" />  
</bag>          
<bag name="emailStateRecipients" lazy="false" inverse="false"
             cascade="save-update" fetch="select">
            <key column="EMAIL_ID" />           
            <one-to-many class="EmailStateRecipient" /> 
</bag>
```

I'm trying to save a new email which has an arraylist of EmailRecipient & EmailStateRecipient objects.

When I tried:

```
this.getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(email);
```

Got an error:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.abc.model.EmailRecipient#0]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.abc.model.EmailRecipient#0]
```

So i changed to:

```
this.getHibernateTemplate().merge(email);
```

Now get this error:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateObjectRetrievalFailureException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.abc.model.EmailRecipient#0]; nested exception is org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.abc.model.EmailRecipient#0]
```

Can somebody help on resolving this. I think I have to check if the object already exists & if yes, then merge or else save. But not sure how. Also if the hbm correct?

Thanks

**Edit:**

EmailRecipient.hbm

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.abc.model">
    <class name="EmailRecipient" table="EMAIL_RCPNT">
        <id name="emailRecipientId" column="EMAIL_RCPNT_ID" type="long">
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">SEQ_RCPNT_ID_PK</param>
            </generator>            
        </id>
        <property name="roleId" column="ROLE_ID" type="long" />     
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Have not added the emailId property to the Recipient.hbm as it is declared as OneToMany in the email.hbm.

Another weird aspect is, this (saveOrUpdate) works fine on my unit test, but does not when running from the app.

Comment: com.abc.model.EmailRecipient#0 - #0 means it has an id of 0, which means it hasn't been saved yet. Can you post the full mapping file of EmailRecipient? I think the problem can be found there (probably wrong generator class)

Comment: Jeroen, I have edited & added the recipient.hbm. Please check that.

Comment: You need to merge element by yourself to the list. So if you have element 1 and you need to add element 1 don't add. Not sure if this suppose to solve, but try. I. Additional try to call clear and than add elementa

Comment: I need to save the Email & then the List of EmailRecipient & stateRecipient objects. So I was thinking, save Email would in turn save the 2 lists as well. but I think I'm missing something.

Comment: @user1495181 : I'm not sure I understand. Can you please put in some sample code. Thanks

Comment: Is the emailRecipientId property of EmailRecipient a `Long` or `long`? Can you add `unsaved-value="0"` and see if it works? And are you setting the emailRecipientId yourself somewhere (even if it is set to 0)?

Comment: Wow! at last solved the issue. The EmailRecipientId was declared as "Long" & changing it to primitive type solved the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow! at last solved the issue.

The EmailRecipientId was declared as "Long" & changing it to primitive type solved the issue.

Thanks to @Jeroen for asking to check that